# how to remove account has suspended message in godaddy hosting after expiration?

Tags: hosting, godaddy

My domain shows "Account Suspended
This Account has been suspended.
Contact your hosting provider for more information." It is expired and I am not going to renew it . But I want to stop that message from appearing whenever someone visits that domain. How can I do that ?

Comment: Unless you actually did not unsubscribe (so are actually due to pay the expenses): yet another reason to not register domains with GoDaddy :-(

Comment: Renew your subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to either renew the subscription, or transfer the domain to another hosting.

You cannot do anything unless you own the domain. Given that it expired, you currently do NOT own the domain.

It is also possible you cannot register the domain elsewhere without renewing on godaddy first and then transferring it away.